# Unable to retrieve code from webpage, because of query string?

Tags: python, string, scrape

I'm trying to write a Python script to retrieve the source code from a web page whose content depends on a query string.  The specific page is: http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100#/charts/hot-100?begin=1&order=position.  This is the Billboard Hot 100 page, which displays the Hot 100 in 10 pages, in groups of 10 songs.  You control the chart positions retrieved via the "begin" query string item, and 10 songs including the "begin" number are returned.  Basically, I want to use Windows Scheduler to automatically run a script that retrieves the 10 pages each week.  I'm not wedded to doing this with Python.

I've used the following script, which retrieves what is seemingly the first page (positions 1 - 10).

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100#/charts/hot-100?begin=1&order=position",r'C:\g\filename.txt')
```

However, when I change the "begin" value to 11, it still retrieves 1 - 10.  Maybe the webpage somehow not permit such an action by a script?  If I input the URL without the query string, it'll return the first 10 positions as well, so I'm thinking one possibility is that the query string isn't being taken into account at all, which may point to a need to a different approach.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks! (and happy holidays!)

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to steal information and data from this remote site?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly.

You are getting the same HTML data as generated by the URL http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100#/charts/hot-100?begin=11&order=position when given in the browser.

This means, the code which retrieves the entries from 11 to 20 is a asynchronous request, like AJAX.

Try this code, it seems to work:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100?begin=11&order=position",r'C:\g\filename.txt')
```

Comment: In this case use firebug to inspect what the webpage is doing in the background or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to `http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100#/charts/hot-100?begin=11&order=position` in your browser? You'll also get results `1-10`. It seems likely that `begin` must be of the form `10n + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at that URL carefully, you'll notice half of it is actually a part of the fragment (which isn't even sent to the server normally). They're probably using AJAX to parse that and show the relevant data.

This seems to work as expected:
http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100?begin=21&order=position